# install elementary os on M2 Solid state drive

Tags: install

The OS does not recognize M2 PCI class 35 solid state drives. (Dell Latitude 3400)
someone knows how to install it on this type of disks.

Comment: I've installed Eos on Samsung m2. Maybe there are some troubles in Bios with ssd recognition?

Answer (score 1):

in Bios configure your sata to ahci mode

Comment: Thanks change on Bios configuration my sata to ahci mode and works perfectly.

Comment: I’m glad, Please mark answer as done Incase others have this issue